# Selecting points from QGIS when button is greyed out?

Tags: qgis, select

I am new to QGIS.

I added mailing addresses from arcgis map server url https://gis.nccde.org/agsserver/rest/services/BaseMaps/Addresses/MapServer. I want to select some points here and move them to a new layer to work with fewer points. But the "select features by area or single click" button is greyed out.

[image]

In arcgis pro, I would use "select" tool to select some points. Then use "copy features" tool to move it to a new layer.

How do I get the select tool to be enabled in QGIS?

Comment: A web service works like a basemap; the service will be used to render items in the canvas, but you can't actually interact with the features beyond identifying them. If you're lucky, sometimes the provider of the web service will offer the GIS data as well. [Try here.](https://nccde.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapAndAppGallery/index.html?appid=8b1f0e3e6f5847219f2b3a23b4a7758f)

Comment: I see. Even in arcgis it is shown under basemaps and not selectable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to convert this layer to geojson and then add it as a vector layer in qgis using ogr2ogr. The features were selectable after that.

`C:\gis>ogr2ogr --config GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL YES -f GeoJSON test.json "https://gis.nccde.org/agsserver/rest/services/BaseMaps/Addresses/MapServer/1/query?where=objectid+%3D+objectid&outfields=*&f=json" OGRGeoJSON`

Comment: In that case you should be adding it as a "feature server" layer in qgis, not a "mapserver" layer

Comment: @ndawson your comment should be the answer. If you can post it as an answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a WMSlayer, which means you are playing with a raster and no object selection is possible.

Comment: Is there a way to convert this to vector and then perform selection?